# Polarized sunglasses makes a quantum measurement device?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light, polarization

Does the experiment of 3 polarizing filters in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcqZHYo7ONs) have anything to do with quatum? 
I don't think so.

Comment: Yes I see the down-votes. Apparenty people like me don't have so much spare time to type all the words to describe the question. If you have time, why don't you just watch the video for a few seconds and complete the question as you like? Giving negative reputation points to new users is not beneficial to the community. And, the most important, this question is **clearly** very **clear**. Both users answering my question have no problem understanding it.

Comment: I'm not sure though, whether the downvotes are due to the closure of this question. If it is, then that's OK. If there are actually 2 people downvoting this question, why? We are having a good discussion here, and I have already got an answer that I wanted. Everyone's pleased. If you don't want to see this kind of question, you can just leave and let this question fade out through time, or even close it in case this question is bumped up at some point in the future. **But NOT downvoting.** I'm sorry to see S. McGrew and Bill Alsept who helped me both get downvotes.

Comment: And, for your information, giving me downvotes won't punish me. I have a successful experience asking this question(despite the downvotes to McGrew and Bill Alsept). I'll definitely post a similar question again if I have one in the future. You may give me downvotes, or even ban my account. I don't care. The only thing that will stop me, is people like S. McGrew and Bill Alsept don't reply to me any more. Well, let's see. And I'm NOT gonna edit my question to make it reopen. For what? An answer? I already got one. Rep points? You're kidding me. Why do I spent so much time doing useless things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:The video shows one experiment with three polarizers, and describes a second experiment but does not show it.  In the first experiment it is shown that although two polarizers with a relative orientation of 90 degrees will block essentially all light, inserting another polarizer oriented at 45 degrees between the two allows a sizable fraction of the light to pass through.  The second experiment, only described and not shown, requires the use of pairs of entangled photons, and is not really relevant to the question, which in essence asks if quantum mechanics is necessary to explain the results of the first experiment. End Edit

Although the three-polarizer experiment in the video *can* be explained by the quantum properties of photons, it does not in itself prove that photons exist.  Maxwell's equations, in their original un-quantized form, predict the same results that are observed in the three-polarizer experiment.  A wave traveling on a stretched wire will exhibit the same behavior. So, quantum mechanics is not necessary for explaining the first experiment's results.

The "quantumness" of light is evidenced in the second experiment (described but not shown in the video), in which the light consists of entangled photons.  Note that the existence of photons is *assumed* in that description.  What *is* shown there is that entanglement -in the quantum sense- actually occurs.  Again, though, the existence of photons is assumed, not proven.

The video simply shows that light passing through polarizers behaves the way we would expect if we assume that light consists of photons; it does not provide proof that photons exist or even that light has quantum properties, because there are other, classical, explanations for the results shown.

The existence of photons is proven, instead, by other experiments such as the photoelectric effect, the black-body spectrum, and detection of extremely attenuated light as individual quanta -- none of which can be explained by Maxwell's equations or other classical physics.

Comment: Waves in wires, water or sound need a medium to travel in. You do not have a medium when it comes to light. The photons are on their own. Billions of coherent photons only resemble waves, like hundreds of   Soldiers marching Outward from a single location in every direction. The individual soldiers marching in step would resemble rings of waves moving outward. Otherwise waves of marching soldiers. Maxwells equations are mathematics and do not represent reality. Your argument is like saying you can calculate where the balls will land on a Galton board But that does not prove there are balls.

Comment: Yep. The first paragraph of your answer describes what I think. I feel wrong about the experiment in the video because the outcome of the experiment will be the same no matter we think light is quantum or electromagnetic field.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described the experiments, since the asker has not done so.

Comment: OK, I edited the answer to describe the first experiment.  The second really isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: @BillAlsept _Maxwells equations are mathematics and do not represent reality._ Let's throw away all physics then.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, quantum is a Latin word for amount and in physics generally means the smallest unit of physical property or energy. In your sunglasses experiment, this would be the individual photons passing or not passing through.

Comment: I'd say the three filter experiment alone *does not* demonstrate the quantum nature of light.   It does not, for example, depend on the existence of photons.  The results can be explained simply using the vector nature of light waves.  Where the quantum nature came in is when the author of the video invoked entangled pairs of photons.  The polarizing filters are still a key part of the experiment, but once entanglement is introduced it's a different experiment.

Comment: @S.McGrew it will still come down the photons. What is the vector or wave nature of light if not billions of individual photons?? No one can explain what a light wave is without individual photons. They may say words like electromagnetic field but that’s just kicking the can down the road. When it comes down to it, it’s still billions of individual photons that make up light.

Comment: Sure it's true that light consists of photons.  But the fact that light has vector properties is not proof that light consists of photons.  Water waves have vector properties, but that does not prove that water consists of molecules.

Comment: @S.McGrew That’s just it, if light is not photons, no one can tell you what it is. Also, photons have vector properties so that makes them even more qualified to represent light or light vectors. What else could? No one ever has an answer for that.

Comment: I should clarify that.  Water waves have a different sort of vector property.  Let's consider waves on a guitar string instead: transverse waves which will behave very much like light in a polarization experiment.    Maxwell's equations are not intrinsically quantized, but they describe waves that would behave just as shown in the 3-polarizer experiment.

Comment: @S.McGrew water waves, sound waves or even guitar strings all have different properties than so called light waves. Light does not have a medium to work with. Water waves definitely have a medium and need gravity to work. You wouldn’t even have water waves without gravity, kinetic displacement of molecules or one of the  multiple forces involved.

Comment: No argument there.  I'm just saying that the simple experiment showing that three polarizers at 0, $theta$, and 90 degrees (where $theta$ is between zero and 90) pass more light than two polarizers at 0 and 90 does not prove that photons exist.  The proof comes from other experiments such as the photoelectric effect, the black body emission spectrum, and measurement of extremely attenuated light beams.

Comment: @S.McGrew I hear what you’re saying but the photoelectric effect, black body emissions or any light beam are made of photons. A single photon or billions of photons through any number of polarizers can be derived physically or mathematically by individual photons.

Comment: @S.McGrew Guitar wave is actually quantized because of the finite length (just like angular momentum in Bohr atom). Can you give an example that is not quantized at all but still satisfies the three layer polarization experiment?

Comment: @OktayDoğangün yes the vibration or cycle is limited to the length of the string. Like the oscillations of a spring or pendulum. If you were to start a spring oscillating and launch it into space, The oscillation would continue as the spring traveled along at a certain constant speed. This is one way you can visualize a photon traveling through space and oscillating at a certain frequency as it moves at a constant speed. The energy is mostly in the speed or frequency of the oscillation.

Comment: @BillAlsept Thanks. But actually I was asking S.McGrew for a better counter example for the same behavior of a polarization experiment, but in classical physics, which demonstrates that it is not proving the quantum nature of the photon.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün yes you are right there are no unquantized examples that satisfies the three polarizer experiment. At least not without inventing some other undescribable or on accountable theory.

Comment: I feel wrong about the experiment in the video because the outcome of the experiment will be the same no matter we think light is quantum or electromagnetic field. And that's why I'm posting this question. But, thanks to your answer, now I start to understand how the video maker is thinking. BTW, @Oktay Doğangün, there **is** a counter example. Just imagine an infinite string as infinit tiny mass dots, and 3 tiny gaps that are totally inelastic and smooth.

Comment: @huhiha What most people fail to realize is the polarizers are not just filters. Photons that make it through also turn and become aligned or polarized with the slit as they go through even if they weren’t completely polarized when they went in.

Comment: @huhiha I couldn't get the direction of your example.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün, If the guitar string is very long, is rigidly fixed at one end, and has an absorber at the other end, waves of any wavelength can be launched from the rigidly fixed end.